# An isosceles trapezium

Tags: geometry

Consider an isosceles trapezium $ABCD$ with $AB = CD$ and $AD = 3BC$. Let $P$ be the middle of $BC$ and $Q$ be the middle of $AD$. Find the angle $APD$ if it is twice the angle $BQC$. Seems to be a simple school-level problem, however I do not see the way to solve it. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Construct the point $F$ at the intersection of $BQ$ and $AP$ and take $E$ to be the midpoint of $AP$. We know that $\frac{BP}{AQ}=\frac{1}{3}$ so $FP= AP/4$. Thus $F$ is the midpoint of $EP$.

The assumption that $\angle APD = 2\angle BQC$ implies that $QF$ is the bisector of the angle $\angle EQP$. Thus, in triangle $EQP$ the line $FQ$ is a bisector and a median in the same time, which means that $EQ=PQ$. On the other hand we already know that $EP=EQ$, so the triangle $EPQ$ is equilateral. This proves that $\angle APD = 120^\circ$ and $\angle BQC = 60^\circ$.

Comment: Sorry, but how does $∠APD=2∠BQC$ implies that $QF$ is the bisector of the angle $∠EQP$ and why do we know that $EP=EQ$?

Comment: @kissanpentu Consider $E$ as the center of the circle circumscribed about $\triangle APQ$. Then $AE=EQ=EP$ are the radii (this also gives $\angle EPQ=\angle EQP$). Then $\angle APD=2\angle BQC$ gives $\angle EPQ=2\angle BQP$. Since $\angle EPQ=\angle EQP$, we get the result.

Comment: @kissanpentu: $E$ is the midpoint of $AP$ and the triangle $APQ$ is rectangle. This means that the triangle $EPQ$ is isosceles and the angles $EPQ$ and $EQP$ are equal. Since the angle $FQP$ is half the angle $APQ$ by hypothesis, it follows that it is also half the angle $EQP$ and thus $QF$ is the bisector of this angle.

Answer (score 0):

Let $BP=x, \angle APQ=\theta$, $PQ=h$. Then $\tan \theta=\frac{3x}{h}$ and $\tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{x}{h}$ and $\frac{\theta}{2}\in(0^{\circ},90^{\circ}).$

$$\tan \theta=\frac{2\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}=3\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$$

$$\implies \tan\frac{\theta}{2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\implies \theta=60
^{\circ}$$